# About the long run behaviour of markov chains

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I'm stuck in the following exercise:    *:(*

In certain town, a sunny day is followed by another sunny day with probability .9, whereas a rainy day is followed by another rainy day with probability .2. Supposing that there are only sunny or rainy days, in the long run of what fraction of days is it sunny?

And the "partial" solution is:

If $p$ is the long-term probability (aka equilibrium point) that it is sunny, then the probability that it is sunny on a following day is also $p$, so: $\Box p + \Box (1-p) = p$

Likewise the probability that it is not sunny on the subsequent day is: $\Box p + \Box (1-p) = (1-p)$.

The problem is I don't know how to fill the boxes with the given information; once the boxes are filled,  I'm just gonna solve the system of equations for p.

Can somebody help me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a fixed probability of being sunny. So you can calculate the probability that it is sunny today using the steady state probabilities for yesterday and demand it equals the steady state probability.

So if $p$ is the steady state probability it is sunny, you have $$ p(0.9) + (1-p)(0.8) = p$$

The left hand side gives you the contribution from yesterday being a sunny day (and it transitioning to another sunny day with probability $.9$) and from yesterday being rainy (and it transitioning to being sunny today with probability $.8.$).

Hopefully, solving this for $p$ gives you the same answer as the corresponding equation for today being rainy $$ p(0.1)+(1-p)(0.2) = 1-p $$

Comment: Is there another name for the "steady state probability"?

Comment: @AaronMartinez stationary distribution

Comment: and limiting distribution isn't equivalent?

Comment: @AaronMartinez uhh, there's some distinctions here and honestly I'm a bit rusty on the terminology. I think in most common terminology a stationary distribution is any distribution that doesn't change in time, whereas a limiting distribution is a distribution that every initial state evolves toward. A limiting distribution is always stationary (and doesn't exist for all MCs) whereas a stationary distribution is not necessarily a limiting distribution (consider if the MC is reducible or periodic)

Comment: alright :) I asked this because my professor haven't talk about anything of stationary distribution,  but he already give us the homework that involves the stationary distribution..it's weird haha

Answer (score 0):

The transition matrix: $M = \begin{pmatrix}
        P_{SS} & P_{SR} \\
        P_{RS} & P_{RR} \\
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0.9 & 0.1 \\
        0.8 & 0.2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}.$

Let the initial state be $x_0=(1,1).$

In the next period: $x_1=x_0\cdot M=(1,1)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        0.9 & 0.1 \\
        0.8 & 0.2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=(1.7,0.3).$

In the $n$-th period: $x_n=x_{n-1}M.$

In the long run $(n\to\infty)$:

$$x=xM \Rightarrow x(M-I)=0 \Rightarrow $$
$$(x^1,x^2)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.1 & \  \  \ 0.1 \\
       \ \ \ 0.8 & -0.8 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=0 \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
-0.1x^1+0.8x^2=0 \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \  \  \   x^1+  \  \  \  \  \  x^2=1 \\
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x^1=\frac{8}{9} \\ 
x^2=\frac{1}{9} \\
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Interpretation: 

$$x=xM \Rightarrow (x^1,x^2)=(x^1,x^2)\begin{pmatrix}
        0.9 & 0.1 \\
        0.8 & 0.2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=0 \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^1=x^1\cdot 0.9+x^2\cdot 0.8 \\ 
x^2=x^1\cdot 0.1+x^2\cdot 0.2
\end{cases},$$

which are the same equations given by @spaceisdardgreen if one considers $x^1=p$ and $x^2=1-p.$

Comment: Thanks :) (I don't know who gave you -1 )

Comment: This might be due to the fact that this answer reproduces @spaceisdarkgreen's one, posted 10 days before.

Comment: Aaron Martinez and Did, thank you for your comments. I am relatively new to this forum and it is useful to know the criteria...

Comment: also I think you should write @AaronMartinez instead of AaronMartinez to notify the users about your comment

Comment: @AaronMartinez, thank you. I did, but a message appeared reading something like the user will be notified automatically. I will from now on. :)

Comment: yes do it, I already received the notification from your comment